# I cannot get Rainbow Text to work. Am i doing something wrong here?

Tags: html, css

So currently i am finishing a website via Codeanywhere for one of my college classes and i can't seem to get rainbow text to work with my code.

I have attempted to work through this >> https://w3bits.com/rainbow-text/ 
But with no successful outcomes being made.

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  .navbar-item img {
    max-height: 50px;
  }
  .column {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 3px black;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #201f20;
  }
  .rainbow-text {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red, violet);
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 24px;
    animation: rainbow 8s ease infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rainbow {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 25%
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero-body">
  <div class="container has-text-centered">
    <h1 class="title" style="">
      1st Level - Clearnet
    </h1>
    <hr style="background-color: grey; margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <div class="column">
      <a imageanchor="1"><img align="right" src="../images/imagine.jpg" border="0"></a>
      <div class="ranbow-text">
        <p class="subtitle">
          Imagine there is a large paragraph of text here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So essentially i am attempting to get "imagine there is a large paragraph of text here" to be rainbow coloured. So far i have failed and now need help.

Comment: `<div class="ranbow-text">` — You misspelt *rainbow*. (Off-topic. Problem caused by a typo. Voting to close).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo in `<div class="ranbow-text">` you are missing an 'i' -> `<div class="rainbow-text">`.
**In addition**, your styles will only apply if the window is over `1025px` wide as per your media query, so when running the code in the small box in `stackoverflow.com` it won't work even when you fix the typo. It is also possible that you are developing with the dev tools open in the same window and that takes some of your width and thus you are unable to see the rainbow colors.

See working example from your code below:

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .navbar-item img {
    max-height: 50px;
  }
  .column {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 3px black;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #201f20;
  }
  .rainbow-text {
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, violet, indigo, blue, green, yellow, orange, red, violet);
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 800% 800%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size: 24px;
    animation: rainbow 8s ease infinite;
  }
  @keyframes rainbow {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 25%
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="hero-body">
  <div class="container has-text-centered">
    <h1 class="title" style="">
      1st Level - Clearnet
    </h1>
    <hr style="background-color: grey; margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <div class="column">
      <a imageanchor="1"><img align="right" src="../images/imagine.jpg" border="0"></a>
      <div class="rainbow-text">
        <p class="subtitle">
          Imagine there is a large paragraph of text here
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was such a rookie mistake i made with the typo but thank you again!!!